# Opencart Flags age away

Tags: discussion, flags

I have flagged 3 Opencart questions so far.

- 1 is pending (Flagged it around 2 days ago)
- 1 has aged away
- 1 was retracted by me (because it was taking too long for any
  action to happen and tbh I thought it would age away as well)

I am getting a feeling most of my opencart flags would age away. I know it seems too early to say that as I have only flagged thrice but as I have noticed so far, only a small percentage of users here use the Opencart tag. What can be done to help the opencart flags from not ageing away?

Comment: What did you flag them for closing? Well, the close vote queue is too full for ages now. Atm, 8.7k questions are awaiting reviews.

Comment: Maybe the queue has too many waiting to be reviewed. I had marked all of them as 'too broad'. But as I have noticed, actions for my flags for other tags are being taken as well. Not immediately but they usually don't age away. @BDL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because other tags that have more traffic on their questions, which includes users with enough rep to close vote them. When they close vote a question your flag on that question is automatically marked as `Helpful`, but tags with less traffic are put in the queue which is currently at over 8K questions.

Comment: So i should assume most of my flags would age away for opencart ? and probably stop flagging

Comment: @MehravishTemkar Don't stop flagging but instead, suggest `edit` on the post and add `PHP` tag if they don't already have it. As PHP is a very high traffic tag it will bring the post to notice.

Comment: the php tag idea is really nice thanks :) mostly the questions that I flag or I want to flag are 'How to do this?' which have no efforts done to do it else i usually answer or edit